# Do I need a UK transit visa travelling from the Netherlands to India

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, dutch-residents

I am an Indian and have a Netherlands Type-1 residence permit. I am travelling from Amsterdam to New Delhi and will be transiting in LHR. Do I need a transit visa?

In the exemptions it says if you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area then you do not need a transit visa.

Can I consider my Netherlands residence permit as common format residence permit or is there a difference between the two?